# Can I change the color of individual static tiles?

Tags: 8.0, tiles

I like to keep all of my primary communication functions (e.g.: Phone, Messaging, Mail, People) up near the top of my Start screen. However, this means a large chunk of my screen is pretty much all one color - whatever the default tile color is for my chosen theme.

Is there a way I can choose for some of these tiles to be a different color, to break up the monotony? I know part of the issue is because most of these are set to the smallest tile size, but I'd rather leave them that way so I have more room for other tiles I want access to without scrolling. Is there something I can do about the colors of these small tiles, or is this just the trade-off I have to live with?

Comment: take a look at this site, a lot of helpfull apps: http://conversations.nokia.com/2013/04/10/how-to-create-awesomely-artistic-windows-phone-start-screens/

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the tile colours, they are decided by the app. But...

you can install apps that create custom "launcher" tiles for many of the phone's functions. Such an app is [Wiztiles](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/wiztiles/54397d90-7f29-46b3-81b9-f78c3fd3b779). How useful they are depends on your use cases, though.